# How to close all open ul's

Tags: jquery, treeview

I have a treeview with accordion which is working, but I want to collapse all previously opened items when a different one is clicked.

For example, in my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/qr1f2mL7/12/), clicking on 'Beverages' will expand it. Then clicking on 'Food' will expand that one. I want 'Beverages' to collapse when 'Food' is clicked on, and vice versa.

I tried adding a new class in addition to the `caret` class thinking to remove all `caret-down` classes prior to the toggler function but I couldn't figure out how to call it before that click function. Would someone please explain how to close all previous expanded items and then expand the one that was clicked on?

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.box::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.check-box::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <span class="caret">Beverages</span>
  <ul class="nested">
    <li>Water</li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>
      <span class="caret">Tea</span>
      <ul class="nested">
        <li>Black Tea</li>
        <li>White Tea</li>
        <li>
          <span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li>Sencha</li>
            <li>Gyokuro</li>
            <li>Matcha</li>
            <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="caret">Food</span>
  <ul class="nested">
    <li>Water</li>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>  
      <span class="caret">Tea</span>
      <ul class="nested">
        <li>Black Tea</li>
        <li>White Tea</li>
        <li>
          <span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
          <ul class="nested">
            <li>Sencha</li>
            <li>Gyokuro</li>
            <li>Matcha</li>
            <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need to remove the relevant classes from any `.caret` and its sibling `ul.nested` which is *not* a parent of the `.caret` which is clicked. This can be done most simply using a combination of jQuery's `closest()`, `children()`, `,parents()` and `find()` methods. Try this:

```js
let $carets = $('.caret').on('click', e => {
  let $caret = $(e.target);
  
  // display the clicked item
  $caret.toggleClass('caret-down');
  $caret.closest('li').children('.nested').toggleClass('active');
  
  // hide the rest
  let $parentCarets = $caret.parents('li').children('.caret'); 
  $carets.not($parentCarets).removeClass('caret-down').closest('li').find('.nested').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.box::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.check-box::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="caret">Beverages</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>
        <span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li>
            <span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="caret">Food</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>
        <span class="caret">Tea</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Black Tea</li>
          <li>White Tea</li>
          <li>
            <span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sencha</li>
              <li>Gyokuro</li>
              <li>Matcha</li>
              <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```